# Why am I get the error "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, string, int, concatenation

This is only a fraction of what my program is going to be so I'm just creating it piece by piece. So all I'm trying to do right now is have my program add a "*" to ast1 if the input is less than or equal to 10 but I keep getting the error "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" and I'm not completely sure why. Can someone throw me a bone here and help me out.

```
ast1 = "*"
count = 0

while (True):
    n = int(input("Enter a number between 0 - 100:"))
    if n<=10:
        ast1 = ast1 + 1 #This is where the error is occuring


print(ast1)
```

EDITED CODE: How can I get this program to terminate/break when the user enters "done"?

```
ast1 = ""
ast2 = ""
ast3 = ""
ast4 = ""


while (True):
    n = int(input("Enter a number between 0 - 100:"))
    if n>=0 and n<=25:
        ast1 = ast1 + "*"
    elif n>25 and n<=50:
        ast2 = ast2 + "*"
    elif n>50 and n<=75:
        ast3 = ast3 + "*"
    elif n>75 and n<=100:
        ast4 = ast4 + "*"
    else:break


print(ast1)
print(ast2)
print(ast3)
print(ast4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to do right now is have my program add a "*" to ast1 if the input is less than or equal to 10

You should do it like that then:

```
ast1 = ast1 + '*'
```

Or, even shorter:

```
ast1 += '*'
```

If you want to use math operators, you could use multiplier:

```
# will set ast1 to '**'
ast1 = ast1 * 2
```

But the second time you'll do the multiplication, of course, you'll have `'****'`. Not sure if that's what you've wanted.

You could multiply an asterisk directly though - like `'*' * 3`. It will return `'***'`.

Comment: No that's not what I want although you did give me a little more knowledge. What I'm doing for my homework is creating a program that will take the input of any number from 0-100 until the input applied is the string "done" then from there i'll print the amount of asterisks for each number from [0,25](25,50](50,75](75,100]. But I like to work through my homework in small parts.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ast1` variable contains  `*` which is defined as string and 1 is defined as integer so string plus integer concatenation won't be possible. It won't be possible to do arithmetic operations on string variable and an integer variable.

Comment: So if I want to add an "*" to ast1 everything the input is <=10 I need to create another variable to multiply ast1 by "n" amount of times the input <=10?

Comment: your ast1 variable contains the string `*`. Convert the int `1` to string like `ast1 + str(1)`

Answer (score 0):

this

```
ast1 = ast1 + 1 #This is where the error is occuring
```

should be

```
ast1 = ast1 + str(1)
```

Numbers need to be explicitly type-casted to string in Python, especially in String operations.